# How to display gradle java compile warning in Jenkins pipeline warnings plugin

Tags: gradle, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, compiler-warnings, javac

I have a build-job defined by Jenkinsfile and I would like to run WarningsPublisher Jenkis plugin to display the output of the gradle build warnings (including errorprone output).

Is there a documentation for WarningsPublisher plugin DSL? How can I add the gradle build output warning to this plugin?

```
node {

  stage('Build/Test artifacts') {
    sh "./gradlew clean build"
  }

  stage('Code quality') {
    step([$class: 'WarningsPublisher', canComputeNew: false, canResolveRelativePaths: false, defaultEncoding: '', excludePattern: '', healthy: '', includePattern: '', messagesPattern: '', parserConfigurations: [[parserName: 'Java Compiler', pattern: '???.txt']], unHealthy: ''])
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Posting your own solution as the answer might be an option.